# Can I call 'this' on an object in an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, this

Can you do this, Call this on an object in array of object litterals?

```js
var array = [
    { name: 'Eric', fullName: this.name + 'Smith'},
    { name: 'Joe', fullName: this.name + 'Shmoe'},
  ];
```

Comment: what happens when you try? It's not hard to check this and see that you can't

Comment: You can try getters like this: `get fullName(){return this.name + ' Smith'}` instead of `fullName: this.name + 'Smith'`.

Comment: it thinks this is "window". try replacing this with (this == window), if strict it's undefined, in node it's undefined or global, i'm not sure. otherwise you can do what you want by mapping over it. http://hastebin.com/winuxutada.php

Comment: It just gives me undefined

Comment: and I am trying to do this in node